# Combining geometry proximity nodes with cloth sim problem

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, cloth-simulation, geometry

I'm trying to create something like this simple mograph animation, where cards rise up in proximity with another object and slightly bend:

[image: example]

I'm trying to do so by combining cloth and geometry nodes, I've managed to make the cards rise up in proximity with a sphere like here:

[image]

But in order to combine cloth simulation to bend the cards I need to "realize instances" which cancels the proximity transform animation like shown here where you can only see the cube colliding with the cards:

[image]

Here's my node setup:
[image]

thank you!